# A column with two divs and another with one

Tags: css, html

What would i put in the css to have one div ontop of another div (both squares are 10x10) and have another column with a div that is 10x20?

Let me rephrase that so its a little simpler, i want one big square that's 20x20. On the left half of that shape, it needs two 10x10 squares, one ontop of the other. On the right side, i need a div that is 10x20.

Please help need this for a class

Comment: We don't do your homework for you. What have you tried?

Comment: tried to put the two squares in one div and float that next to the other rectangle. Was that the right thing to do?

Comment: You should update your question with the code you tried and didn't work. You're more likely to get help if you show an honest effort.

Comment: fixed it, thanks though, ill give you upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can use css's [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position) property to absolutely position elements to set top and left coordinates. You'll also need to use the `height` and `width` properties to size the boxes.

Comment: i know  the height and width, just not sure how to do the positioning, and itd be better if i did it with absolute position

Comment: That page has examples of using `position`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<div id="bigBox">
     <div class="leftBox"></div>
     <div class="leftBox"></div>
     <div id="rightbox">
</div>

<style>
    #bigBox { position: relative; width: 20px; height: 20px;}
    .leftBox {position: absolute; left: 0; height: 10px; width: 10px; }
    .rightBox {position: absolute; right: 0; width: 10px; height: 20px;}
</style>
```

Comment: -1 "Homework means the question is requesting help with school homework. This lets potential answerers know that they SHOULD guide the student in solving the problem, and SHOULD NOT simply show the complete answer." And your code is wrong. End the `rightbox` div. It should be an `id` in the CSS, not a class. And lowercase.

Comment: Sorry I'm relatively new around here, didn't know there were 'homework' rules.

Comment: It's not a "rule" just pointless to throw the answer out as the asker won't learn anything. But please, if you're going to answer, make sure your code works. You'll see a lot of people use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show a demo of their code.